# TPL: Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll with AttachedToParent

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, continuations

The [description of AttachedToParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) states

> AttachedToParent: Specifies that the continuation, if it is a child task, is attached to a parent in the task hierarchy. **The continuation can be a child task only if its antecedent is also a child task.**

What does the emphasized part mean? Does the following code contradict this statement?

```
static void Example()
{
    Task antecedent = new Task(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Antecedent begun");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        });
    antecedent.Start();

    Task parent = null;
    parent = new Task(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parent begun");
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            var continuation = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { antecedent }, _ =>
            {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    Console.WriteLine("parent status: {0}", parent.Status);

            }, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
        });
    parent.Start();
    parent.Wait();
}
```

When I run this, it gives this output:

```
Antecedent begun
Parent begun
Parent status: WaitingForChildrenToComplete
```

The continuation task does appear to have been attached to the parent. According to the documentation, to be attached, it must be a child task. But antecedent isn't a child task.

Comment: Continuation task is **not** the same as antecedent, it's a different tasks. What's your question?

Comment: @WMAtm. I'm looking to resolve an apparent ambiguity/contradiction in the documentation. Is `continuation` a child task of `parent`? It appears to be, as the parent waits for children to complete. But the doc states that it cannot be, because the `continuation`'s antecedent is not a child task of `parent`.

Comment: `Continuation` is a child of `parent` task, yes. `Parent` is not aware about what's going on inside the `continuation`, it simply waits for it. You're creating a new task with `WhenAll`, you're not continuing the `antecedent` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want that property to be defined on the child, not the parent ... It should look something like :

```
Task parent = null;

var antecedent = new Task(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Antecedent begun");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}, new CancellationToken(), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
antecedent.Start();

parent = new Task(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent begun");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { antecedent }, _ =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("parent status: {0}", parent.Status);

        });
    });
parent.Start();
parent.Wait();
```

Comment: It's the continuation task (created by `ContinueWhenAll`) that I am attaching to the parent task `parent`, but the antecedent of the continuation task is not a child of `parent`. But the bold text seems to say that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new child task **inside** the `parent` task with directly stating that this is a child task. This is why the the `parent` waits for it. If you see inside the [code of the `ContinueWhenAll`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs,ca53c3b1e37aa2e9), you'll see this line:

```
var starter = TaskFactory.CommonCWAllLogic(tasksCopy);
```

So, the tasks are copied, and after that the new task is internally created, this is why the continuation is marked as child. If you move out the continuation out of `parent`, it wouldn't be wait for:

```
static void Example2()
{
    Task antecedent = new Task(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Antecedent begun");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    });
    antecedent.Start();

    Task parent = new Task(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent begun");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    });
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { antecedent }, _ =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("parent status: {0}", parent.Status);

    }, TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent);
    parent.Start();
    parent.Wait();
}
```

Output for the given code is:

```
Antecedent begun
Parent begun
```